# Excluding kernel modules through /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf does not work

Tags: debian, kernel, boot, kernel-modules, initramfs

I don't want to load the kernel module nouveau on my debian box at startup, so I put the following in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:

```
blacklist ttm
blacklist drm
blacklist nouveau
```

I even did a `update-initramfs -u` but nonetheless those three modules get loaded each time I boot.

Does anyone know why and how to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the answer in [the wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/KernelModuleBlacklisting): the idea is that one does not use `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. 
Instead, say you want to blacklist pcspkr. You create a `pcspkr.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d` and put `blacklist pcspkr` inside. Then run

```
depmod -ae && update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: I see the wiki page says `depmod` is required here, but it sounds nonsense to me. Source: I helped develop modprobe, a while back :-P.  I am not sure why following your answer would be any better, though clearly at least one person found this approach helpful.